# Difference between process and "vanilla" VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hardware, asic

I'm practicing VHDL, and I have a fundamental question about "simple" statements which do not require a process.

I would like to know the difference between

```
c <= a and b;
```

Where the statement is not inside a process, just written after the architecture begin, and

```
process(a,b)
begin
    c <= a and b;
end process;
```

Will these results produce the same thing?
Ty :)

Comment: The first form is a syntactic sugar of the latter form.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements "A concurrent signal assignment statement represents an equivalent process statement that assigns values to signals.", "The process statement equivalent to a concurrent signal assignment statement whose target is a signal name is constructed as follows:...", 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy "The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design."

Comment: And the telling (11.6) "Execution of a concurrent signal assignment statement is equivalent to execution of the equivalent process statement."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two descriptions are equivalent.

The concurrent signal assignment `c <= a and b` is evaluated at each update of any of the argument (`a` or `b`), and the process will also evaluate each time any of the arguments in the sensitivity list is updated (`a` or `b`).

In the simple example it not required to use a `process`, but for more complex expressions, the `process` has the advantage that control structures like `if` and `for` can be used, which is not directly possible in a concurrent signal assignment.  Also, for sequential logic a `process` is required.

Comment: "_`process` has the advantage that control structures like `if` and `for` can be used_": OK for the loops but concurrent signal assignments can also implement `if-elsif-elsif-else` (`sig <= val1 when cond1 else val2 when cond2...`) or `case` control structures (`with...select`).

Comment: "_for sequential logic a process is required_": what about `Q <= D when rising_edge(CLK);`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: Thanks for the additions. I agree that `when-else-...` can substitute `if-then-...` for concurrent assign.  Also, if `if-then-...` is wanted in concurrent assign, then these can be wrapped in a function, so yet another example of how to do without `process`.  For sequential logic I will oppose the concurrent assign using `Q <= D when rising_edge(CLK);`, since tools are likely to fail this; for example Intel Quartus 18.1 synthesis crashes when this construction is presented, thought is legal code, and ModelSim accepts it.

Comment: The form `Q <= D when rising_edge(CLK);` was supported by Altera Quartus II. If Intel Quartus Prime does not accept this, it's a bug introduced into Quartus. It's also supported by Xilinx ISE, Xilinx Vivado and Lattice LSE. It's even possible to write own `rising_edge` functions. This is synthesized correctly in all mentioned tools except for Vivado, which creates latches instead of FFs...

Comment: @Paebbels: To double check if this is a Quartus 18.1 problem, I made a module with only two FFs, one as process and one as concurrent assign using above, and it breaks with "Internal Error: Sub-system: BPM, File: /quartus/db/bpm/bpm_hard_block_util.cpp, Line: 3458 ... Quartus Prime Information ... Version: 18.1.0 Build: 625 Edition: Lite Edition".  ModelSim handles it nicely, showing same behaviour, and when I change the concurrent FF to process like then other it also runs through Quartus.  I can send you my example, but not much to it.  I will try to report to Intel.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of any VHDL one liner as an implied process with the arguments on the RHS of <= in the sensitivity list.
This is why both of the code snippets you wrote are practically equivalent.